# to modify the parameter in the api call and give the csv file as an input

Tags: python

i am trying to make an api cal, since i have many parameters i have put then in csv file with columns:

```
ranges       params     
60,20:58,17  speed,temperature
50,10:48,10  speed,temperature
50,10:48,11  speed,temperature
```

My request code is:

```
response = requests.get(
  'URL',
  params={
      'ranges': '60,20:58,17',
      'parameter': 'speed,temperature'
  },
  headers={
    'Authorization': <MY_AUTH_KEY>
  }
)
```

instead of giving params each time i am trying to pass the csv file so that it takes each row as input, how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a [csv reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), which is pretty common, to get lines of a csv:

```
import csv
with open(<path_to_my_file>, newline='') as csvfile:
    data_rows = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in data_row:
        ranges, params = row
        response = requests.get(
            'URL',
            params={
                'ranges': ranges,
                'parameter': params
            },
            headers={
               'Authorization': <MY_AUTH_KEY>
            }
        )
        # Code to do something with the response
```

Note that  should be the path to your csv file, like `~/Desktop/params.csv`. And of course, you'll have to actually do something with that response inside the `for row in data_row:` loop